# getting an error while trying to enter values in mysql table. The value of data[0] is MICHAEL JACKSON

Tags: java, mysql

```
String insertsql1 = "INSERT INTO ng_albums(ng_singers_id) " +
                    "SELECT ng_singers.ng_singers_id " +
                    "FROM   ng_singers " +
                    "WHERE  ng_singers.name=" + data[0];

PreparedStatement ps1 = (PreparedStatement);
conn.prepareStatement(insertsql1);
ps1.executeUpdate();
```

Error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JACKSON' at line 1

Comment: Stop concatenating your SQL and switch to parameterized queries. Don't expect us to debug issues you create yourself by building strings and leaving yourself open to SQL injection. Google *Little Bobby Tables*.

Comment: Have you tried printing query you are trying to execute? Are you able to execute it on database directly (without Java)? What do you think is missing there? Also that is not how you use prepared statements. Vising official tutorial, use solutions provided there and your problem also will disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be using parameters here instead of string concatenation. You're almost on the right track with the `PreparedStatement`, you just need to set the parameter correctly.

```
String insertsql1 = "INSERT INTO ng_albums(ng_singers_id) SELECT 
     ng_singers.ng_singers_id FROM ng_singers WHERE ng_singers.name= ?";

PreparedStatement ps1=(PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(insertsql1);
ps1.setString(1, data[0]);

ps1.executeUpdate();
```

For more information see [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

As for the reason for your error message, you have not enclosed the value of `data[0]` inside quotes, so SQL doesn't know to treat it as such.